# How to launch the Outlook 365 client with an email including attachments?

Tags: winapi, office365, c++builder

I have an app written in C++Builder 12 that needs to launch the Outlook 365 client with an attachment.

I have tried this, but Outlook 365 does not allow an attachment.

```
ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "mailto:<email>@<domain>.com?subject=Hello&body=Hello%20world&Attach=%34c:\\temp\\test.pdf%34", 0, 0, 1);
```

The way `ShellExecuteA()` launches the client is almost exactly what I need, but it has to allow me to add the attachment(s).

I've looked into this, but I don't want to launch "Outlook", just the Outlook 365 client like `ShellExecuteA()` does.

```
CreateOleObject("Outlook.Application");
```

Comment: Perhaps you can send the email with the attachment directly from the application using the `TIdIMAP4` component?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `TIdIMAP4` can't *send* emails, only *receive* and *manage* them.  You would need `TIdSMTP` to *send* emails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Aha, my bad. I thought `TIdIMAP4Server` was for that part.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `TIdIMAP4` is a client. `TIdIMAP4Server` lets you make your own IMAP server.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately unless the requirements change, I need to load the Outlook 365 client for the user to send the email. Would it be possible to write an .eml file with an attachment and then load the Outlook 365 client with it? If so, is there a component or sample code that would help me?